# Custom controls disabled. There was an internal issue with the rendering process

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin.android

I installed Xamarin 4.2.2.11 (00fa5cc) on VS 2013.

How can I solve this error in designer:
**Custom controls disabled. There was an internal issue with the rendering process.**

[This is my sdk manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB6wo.png)

[This is the designer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM5gJ.png)